# Angularjs how to change $rootScope variables from UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a dynamic web page with angular, the content from the main page should change, but to avoid writing too much code i decided to make it generic, but to know what type of content is being requested i need to send this parameter from a link/button with a ng-click, this would'nt be a problem but when i have to change the controllers i can't read the parameter.

```
ng-click="name='Name change'"
```

Here i'm trying to change a $rootScope variable named name, i tried

```
ng-click="$rootScope.name='Name change'"
```

even with a service function, but looks like doesn't work (i don't know too much about angularjs so i tried )

```
 ng-click="$service.cambiarTipo='Name change'"
```

i made a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1BN76SbUAHuOSHs02gpL?p=preview

If you check the console log, you will see that the variable it's undefined, obviously if i change $rootScope.name from a controller i can see it from the other controller, but that's not useful since i need that feed from the user not the controller.

How i can change a rootScope variable from html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here'a one using a shared service between the two controller without using $rootscope at all. http://plnkr.co/edit/maKNHgVH20GxTJeCEveh

Note that ng-click is calling the service function. I'm assuming the function is for changing the name.

```
ng-click="service.cambiarTipo('Name change')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using $rootScope all that much, let alone modifying it from the template. With that said, you can assign $rootScope to a $scope variable and access from the template like normal scoped variable. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OT4Wvnl5IWXwF9ccFiUa?p=preview)

Controller:
`$scope.rs = $rootScope`

Template:
`rs.name = 'Name Change'`

I would like to reiterate that this is not something you should be doing as it goes against the angular way.

Comment: If is not the angular way, what i can do to achieve the same?